# XSD Unique constraint not working (still Valid)

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I'm working with this code:

```
<xsd:complexType name="list">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="book" type="bookType" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:unique name="idUnique">
                <xsd:selector xpath="name"/>
                <xsd:field xpath="@id"/>
            </xsd:unique>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The problem is that the unique constraint is not working no matter what I try. I was playing with namespaces, xpath, whole XSD code and still nothing. I'm trying to apply it to this XML file

```
    <list>
       <book>
           <name id="125695">Book Name</name>
           <releaseDate>2012-08-24</releaseDate>
           <author>...
           ...
       </book>
       <book>...<book>
    </list>
```

Whenever I put in another book with the same id, Validation is still successful. I'm starting to be quite desperate. I have no idea what is wrong. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].    You've covered *minimal* but lost *complete*.  You should show the smallest, complete XSD and XML that validates when you believe it should not validate.

Answer (score 0):

Uniqueness constraints must specify both what should be unique and the scope within which it must be unique.  In XSD, they do the first by using the selector and field elements; they do the second by being associated with the element which represents the scope (every identity constraint is scoped to exactly one element).

By placing the uniqueness constraint on the `book` element you have said "no two name/@id attributes in any `book` element may have the same value."  If what you want to say is that no two book/name/@id attributes in the document may have the same value, then you need to place the constraint on the declaration for the outermost element of your document (or any element that will contain all the `book` elements).